# umbraco Contour textfield side by side

Tags: umbraco7, umbraco-contour

Im trying to make a form in contour for umbraco with to text fields. and I want them to be placed side by side, or at the same "horizontal line"

Im new to contour but I can't find a way to do this, an i'm been trying to google it, but without any luck.

So do anyone know if you can do this in contour? or do you need to make it yourself?

as always, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So. I just found out how it can be done. and i'm gonna answer this instead of delete it since i got a upvote.

It's simple. you can build your forms up in rows and cols. so this will give you the tools need for it.